# Block matrix with headings

Tags: matrices, arrays

I created a matrix using easybmat and blkarrary and I would like to label the columns above the matrix.  This is the code I am using and what the matrix looks like at the moment:

```
\usepackage{easybmat}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\[  \mathbb{X} =  \begin{array}{c@{}c} 
\left[   
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
\boldsymbol{\beta}  & x_1 & z_1 & \dots & z_{k-1}\\
\begin{BMAT}[3pt]{ccccc}{ccccccccc}
1 & x_{11} & 1 & \dots  & 0 \\   
1 & x_{21} & 1 & \dots  & 0 \\      
\vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\     
1 & \vdots & 1 & \dots  & 0\\        
\vdots & & &  & \vdots \\ 
1  & \vdots & 0 & \dots  & 0\\   
1 & \vdots & 0 & \dots  & 0\\   
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
1 & x_{n1} & 0 & \dots  & 0\\ 

\end{BMAT}   
\end{blockarray}

\right] 
&  
\begin{array}{l}  
\\[-17mm] \rdelim\}{4}{6mm}[$ \hspace{2mm} Category \hspace{2mm} 1$] \\ \\ 
\\[17mm]  \rdelim\}{4}{6mm}[$\hspace{2mm} Category \hspace{2mm} k$] \\ \\ 
\end{array} \\[-1ex] 
\end{array}  
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the first row in the current matrix , to be the headings of the columns. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem.  In particular, I do not know where `BMAT` comes from.

Comment: Is the empty space under `x_1 z_1 ... z_{k-1}` intentional?

Comment: no, I am trying to place those heading on the lest side ( as headings to the columns of the matrices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I could come up with.  The only thing I don't like about this solution is that I'm having to use `\vphantom` in the very top row of the matrix so that the `.north` anchors line up.  I'm not sure how to fix that whilst still keeping the baseline of the matrix elements lined up.  If anyone else has a solution, please feel free to pitch in.

*This little annoyance has been fixed.  The height of a node in TikZ can be overwritten with the `text height` option.  This is much better than having to use `\vphantom`.*

I'm not completely familiar with `easybmat` and `blkarray`, so instead, I opted to use Ti*k*Z' `matrix` library which allow additional features to be drawn quite easily on a matrix.  Here's the code for what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  matrix,
  positioning,
  decorations,
  decorations.pathreplacing
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbb{X} = 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(m.center)]
  \matrix (m) [
      matrix of math nodes,
      left delimiter={[},
      right delimiter={]},
      row 1/.style={nodes={text height=1ex}}
    ] {
      1      & x_{11} & 1       & \cdots & 0      \\
      1      & x_{21} & 1       & \cdots & 0      \\
      \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      1      & \vdots & 1       & \cdots & 0      \\
      \vdots &        &         &        & \vdots \\
      1      & \vdots & 0       & \cdots & 0      \\
      1      & \vdots & 0       & \cdots & 0      \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \cdots & \vdots \\
      1      & x_{n1} & 0       & \cdots & 0      \\
    };

    \node [above=1ex of m-1-1] {\(\boldsymbol{\beta}\)};
    \node [above=1ex of m-1-2] {\(x_{1}\)};
    \node [above=1ex of m-1-3] {\(z_{1}\)};
    % \node [above=1ex of m-1-4] {\\(\cdots\)};
    \node [above=1ex of m-1-5] {\(z_{k-1}\)};

    \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] 
          ([xshift=3ex]m-1-5.north east) -- ([xshift=3ex]m-4-5.south east)
          node [pos=0.5, right=1ex] {Category 1};
    \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] 
          ([xshift=3ex]m-6-5.north east) -- ([xshift=3ex]m-9-5.south east)
          node [pos=0.5, right=1ex] {Category \(k\)};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

To illustrate specifically the issue with the top row, compare the following two images which shows the node boundaries.

With `\vphantom`:
[image: with vphantom]
Without `\vphantom`:
[image: without vphantom]

For completeness-sake, the original code had:

```
      right delimiter={]},
    ] {
      1      & \vphantom{1}x_{11} & 1       & \vphantom{1}\cdots & 0      \\
      1      & x_{21} & 1       & \cdots & 0      \\
```

Comment: `nodes={anchor=center}`

Comment: @percusse I'm aware of that, but that doesn't work as it doesn't align the baselines of the nodes.  This results in `x_{11}` being too high compared to the other symbols.

Comment: You can add `text depth` to account for subscripts

Comment: @percusse The issue actually was the text height, not the text depth; but thanks for pointing me in right direction :)

Comment: You will need text depth eventually later

Comment: @percusse In another situation maybe, but in this case I don't think so; unless I missed what you're referring to.  There's no need for the bottom of the nodes to line up as we have no annotations on the bottom of the matrix.

Comment: If you had text depth here then the height of `x_{11}` wouldn't spill like that because of the subscripts.

Comment: @percusse Well, I tried it, and adjusting the text depth *does not* cause the top of the nodes to line up (though a sufficiently large text depth does cause the bottom of the nodes to line up)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \mathbb
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{X} = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-col=6]
      \beta  & x_1    & z_1     &        & z_{k-1} \\
      1      & x_{11} & 1       & \cdots & 0      & \Block{4-1}{\quad \text{Category 1}}\\
      1      & x_{21} & 1       & \cdots & 0      \\
      \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      1      & \vdots & 1       & \cdots & 0      \\
      \vdots &        &         &        & \vdots \\
      1      & \vdots & 0       & \cdots & 0      & \Block{4-1}{\quad \text{Category } k}\\
      1      & \vdots & 0       & \cdots & 0      \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \cdots & \vdots \\
      1      & x_{n1} & 0       & \cdots & 0      \\
\CodeAfter [sub-matrix/xshift=2mm]
  \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{4-5}{\}}
  \SubMatrix{.}{6-1}{9-5}{\}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]